# Resampling a Pandas dataframe while forward filling (ffill) the values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where a snippet looks like this

```
    Time                    Temperature
19  2019-01-01 11:48:51     23.798
20  2019-01-01 11:48:53     23.832
21  2019-01-01 11:48:54     NaN
22  2019-01-01 11:48:55     23.817
23  2019-01-01 11:48:56     NaN
```

I want to resample this to '2S' while making sure that the last measured value will replace any NaNs.

```
df.resample('2S', on='Time').mean().ffill()
```

A snippet of the result looks like this

```
                        Temperature
Time            
2019-01-01 11:48:52     23.832
2019-01-01 11:48:54     23.817
2019-01-01 11:48:56     23.809
```

Notice the value at timestamp t=54s. What I want is the temperature 23.832 from t=53s, since that is the last recorded value at this timestamp. Instead it fillings with the value from t=55s

This is the output I desire. I don't care if it is sampled on odd or even seconds.

```
                        Temperature
Time            
2019-01-01 11:48:52     23.798
2019-01-01 11:48:54     23.832
2019-01-01 11:48:56     23.817
```

**Edit 1:**
After a reply, I tried the following:

```
df.ffill().resample('2S', on='Time').first()
```

But this gives the following result, where the new t=52s is equal to the old t=t=53s, which is not the behavior I am after...

```
                        Temperature
Time            
2019-01-01 11:48:50     23.798
2019-01-01 11:48:52     23.832
2019-01-01 11:48:54     23.832
2019-01-01 11:48:56     23.817
```

Comment: First do `fillna(method='ffill')` then try resampling..

Comment: forward fill first, then resample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit #3:

```
idx = df.resample('2S').asfreq().index
df.reindex(df.index.union(idx)).ffill().resample('2S').asfreq()
```

Output:

```
                     Temperature
Time                            
2019-01-01 11:48:50          NaN
2019-01-01 11:48:52       23.798
2019-01-01 11:48:54       23.832
2019-01-01 11:48:56       23.817
```

---

Edit #2:

```
idx = df.resample('2S').asfreq().index
df.reindex(df.index.union(idx)).bfill().resample('2S').first()
```

Output:

```
                     Temperature
Time                            
2019-01-01 11:48:50       23.798
2019-01-01 11:48:52       23.832
2019-01-01 11:48:54       23.817
2019-01-01 11:48:56          NaN
```

---

EDIT:

```
df.reindex(df.index.union(df.resample('2S').asfreq().index))\
  .interpolate().resample('2S').asfreq()
```

Output:

```
                     Temperature
Time                            
2019-01-01 11:48:50          NaN
2019-01-01 11:48:52      23.8150
2019-01-01 11:48:54      23.8245
2019-01-01 11:48:56      23.8170
```

---

Do you want to resample two seconds on odd seconds or even seconds?

```
df.ffill().resample('2S', on='Time', base=1).mean()
```

Output:

```
                    Temperature
Time                            
2019-01-01 11:48:51       23.798
2019-01-01 11:48:53       23.832
2019-01-01 11:48:55       23.817
```

Or just on even number of seconds:

```
df.ffill().resample('2S', on='Time').mean()
```

Output:

```
                     Temperature
Time                            
2019-01-01 11:48:50      23.7980
2019-01-01 11:48:52      23.8320
2019-01-01 11:48:54      23.8245
2019-01-01 11:48:56      23.8170
```

Comment: based on the comment from the OP I think they are looking for `first` and not `mean`: `df.ffill().resample('2S', on='Time').first()` . . . " at timestamp t=54s. What I want is the temperature 23.832 from t=53s,"

Comment: When I write `df.ffill().resample('2S', on='Time').first()`, I still don't get ther result I am after... :\ The value from t=52s gets copied to t=52s

Comment: Your new edit still doesn't give me the desired output, though I really appreciate your effort. It is a weird request, but it is necessary to simulate how the controller we are using is logging data.

Comment: Are you wanting just to move the data back 1S?  Where does the 23.809 come from in your expected output?

Comment: @ScottBoston I think you misread my post. My expected (/desired) data is below **Edit 2**. There is no value of 23.809 there. Further, your output in your edit 2 is somewhat correct, but the values occur two seconds too early.

Comment: @ViggoTW Okay, take a look at the third edit. :-)   And, to misquote an old cartoon before your time probably.   "Understanding is half the battle."

Answer (score 0):

EDITED to use last, not first. Probably doesn't matter with your sample data, but if you have multiple records in a 2 second period, this will ensure you take the most recent one.

There is an option when resampling to specify what edge of the bin to label the data with. The default for S is left - so the start of the 2 second time period. Changing to `right` I believe gives what you are after.

```
df.resample('2S', on='Time', label='right').last().ffill()

Time                Temperature
2019-01-01 11:48:52 23.798
2019-01-01 11:48:54 23.832
2019-01-01 11:48:56 23.817
2019-01-01 11:48:58 23.817
```